# Has anyone got Hamachi 2 working on EC2 Windows instances?

Tags: vpn, amazon-ec2, p2p, hamachi

I have it running and can see the EC2 instance with a direct tunnel. However, I can't ping the EC2 instance nor can I browse the shared folders.

I am sure of the following:
- File sharing service is running
- Folders are shared

I have tried the following:
- Turning Windows firewall off
- Allowing all TCP and UDP ports and ICMP through Amazon EC2 group policy firewall

The instance is a Windows 2008 DataCentre 32-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems no one is doing this for EC2. In general I'm very disappointed in the level of support/publicity Hamachi gets from LogMeIn. I'm now using an Amazon S3 based solution for the problem.